# How to Enable Code Block "Copy" in VSCode similar to GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Anyone knows how to get "Copy" option in VSCode for code block like we get on github flavored markdown pages?

Online research says "Markdown All in One" extension can do that but I don't see any such option anymore in their latest version.

reference: https://twitter.com/natfriedman/status/1391862005095485440

Comment: your linked twitter post is talking about GitHub... how is it related?